# Basic Primitives - ссылка на объект

Tags: javascript

Строю диаграмму при помощи basic primitives js.
Данные подгружаю через базу данных.
Существуют ли примеры с ссылками на каждый элемент диаграммы?

```
{ id: 1, spouses: [2], title: "Thomas Williams", label: "Thomas Williams", description: "1, 1st husband", image: "/photos/t.png" },
```

вот пример стандартного объекта в библиотеке, как здесь можно задать ссылку на детальную страницу объекта?